# Doubt in understanding a question of basic probability theory

Tags: probability

I am doing the following problem :

In a game of gambling, $3$ dice are rolled and the player bets on a number
chosen from $\{1; 2;...; 6\}$.

If the number on which the player has bet appears $i$ times, $i = 1; 2; 3$, then the player wins $i$ units and if the number does
not appear on any of the three dice, the player loses 1 unit.

Is this gamefair to the player?

Here I don't understand what I need to show to say that the game is fair or not? I defined a random variable $X$ that takes values $ -1,1,2,3 $ with p.m.f $P(X=-1) =$ the probability that he loses $1$ unit, then $P(X=1)=$ probability that he wins 1 unit and similarly the rest..then calculated the expectation and it turned out to be non zero. So can I say now that the game is not fair? Please help.

Comment: Yes, that's what the argument that the game isn't fair should look like. Note that the devil is in the details; particularly, it can be easy to make a mistake on computing those probabilities.

Comment: Hey, JOHN  just an FYI alert.  Downvotes and closed votes are kept track of,  but, as you deleted your most recent post after receiving downvotes, and a close, they count just the same as if not deleted, and the deletion counts against you too.  The privilege of posting questions is blocked for users who've demonstrated a pattern of low quality posts in terms of score, closures, and deleted questions.  So, I'm guessing your okay so far (provided you haven't habitually deleted other questions too; but keep in mind that you are expected to learn from the first few misteps.

Comment: @JOHN  By the way: I'm not threatening anything, 'cuz I can't block questions or answers from anyone.  Nor can Mod's, unless an account is suspended.  I am simply hoping you understand that the SE network, and its sites, will auto-block further questions from an account after meeting some threshold considered to be "enough" low quality, and hence a block from asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each die the player can expect to win ${1\over6}$ units, makes ${1\over2}$ units per simultaneous throw of the three dice. On the other hand the probability that none of the three dice shows the number he has bet on amounts to $\left({5\over6}\right)^3=0.5787$. As $0.5787>{1\over2}$ the game is unfair to the betting player.